# How to remove blank rows in a Power BI Table

Tags: powerbi

I run monthly reports to show month over month impact on our transportation costs.  I need to have a formula that will remove blank rows when there is not a record in the current period or previous period.

```
Routing Current Month   Previous Month
aaaa    100             150
bbbb    125 
cccc    200             210
dddd                    180
```

My formula for trying to deal with this is:

```
MoM PPV =
    IF(OR(ISBLANK([$/Container]), ISBLANK([PREVIOUS MONTH $CONTAINER])),
        BLANK(),
        DIVIDE([OCEAN CONTAINER DIFFERENCE], 'GCF Ocean'[$/Container])
    )
```

EDITED

Answer (score 0):

If your measure returns BLANK(), then power bi desktop automatically remove rows.

```
Measure = CALCULATE( DIVIDE(sum('Table'[Current]), sum('Table'[Previous])) )
```

example:

[image]

EDITED:

```
SumOfPrev =  CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Previous]))


SumOfCurrent =  CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Current]))


Measure = CALCULATE( DIVIDE([SumOfCurrent], [SumOfPrev]) )
```

Comment: My current and previous numbers are a result of a measure.  I tried the above calculations but I am unable to get the measure to divide

Comment: this work also with the measure as in my example

Comment: Still having blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with visual level filter as shown in attached image. It will remove all the blank record which your measure "MoM PPV" code return.
[image: filter representation]